# Logical AND operator on two OR operator lists

Tags: java, mongodb, pattern-matching

I am using the below query `searchQuery` to apply regex.

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
Pattern regex;
BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
for (String s : statistics) {
    regex = Pattern.compile(s);
    DBObject statRegex = new BasicDBObject("_id", regex);
    or.add(statRegex);
}
searchQuery.put("$or", or);
```

Which finds results where the `_id` field, has a value of one of the strings in an array list called `statistics`. (e.g. "Error", "Timeout", ResponseTime"...).

How could I query the database via two `or` lists. For example I want to match where the `_id` field is equal to a string contained in `statistics` and where the `name` field is a string contained in `networks`.

From reading other topics, I think the solution might be with `$elemMatch` although I have a limited understanding of how advanced queries work in `mongoDB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $and and $or in combination

```
test:Mongo > db.test.insert({ _id : "abhi", name : "kumar" })
test:Mongo > db.test.find({ $and : [ {$or : [ { _id : /abhi/ } ]}, {$or : [ { name : /kumar/ } ] } ] })
{ "_id" : "abhi", "name" : "kumar" }
```